# Форма с четырьмя чекбоксами

Tags: javascript, html

Есть N>1 форм на странице с четырьмя чекбоксами в каждой, 2 из которых активны все время. Как переделать этот скрипт, чтобы он менял значение инпутов в форме должным образом?  Сейчас работает в цепочке - если один из инпутов не активен - все, что за ним в скрипте не меняют значения . 
Заранее спасибо.

```js
    function codename(aForm) {
      var count = 0;

      aForm.item_name_1.value = '';
      aForm.amount_1.value = '';
      aForm.item_name_2.value = '';
      aForm.amount_2.value = '';
      aForm.item_name_3.value = '';
      aForm.amount_3.value = '';
      aForm.item_name_4.value = '';
      aForm.amount_4.value = '';

      if (aForm.item1.checked) {
        aForm.item_name_1.value = "interior design";
        aForm.amount_1.value = "10.00";
      }

      if (aForm.item2.checked) {
        aForm.item_name_2.value = "One more variant of interior";
        aForm.amount_2.value = "5.00";
      }

      if (aForm.item3.checked) {
        aForm.item_name_3.value = "Extra fast 1day delivery";
        aForm.amount_3.value = "10.00";
      }

      if (aForm.item4.checked) {
        aForm.item_name_4.value = "Processing fee";
        aForm.amount_4.value = "4.00";
      }
    }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return codename(this)" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">

  <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="Item 1" checked>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="Item 2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="item3" value="Item 3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="item4" value="Item 4" checked>
  <input type="text" name="amount_1">
  <input type="text" name="amount_2">
  <input type="text" name="amount_3">
  <input type="text" name="amount_4">
  <input type="text" name="item_name_1">
  <input type="text" name="item_name_2">
  <input type="text" name="item_name_3">
  <input type="text" name="item_name_4">
  <input type="submit" border="0" name="payment">
</form>
```

Comment: У вас переменной count присвоено статическое значение 1. Напишите более детально что не работает.

Comment: У меня форма , где  SBMT button с атрибутом onclick="codename()" . При нажатии ни один input не изменяет значение

Comment: Передаю теперь уникальные имена каждой форме и при каждом клике вызывается эта функция, которая должна менять значение всех элементов. . .  но она стопорится на первой же строчке document.formname.item_name_1.value='';  С Чем это может быть связано?

Comment: "она стопорится" - 37 человек, прочитавших Ваш вопрос на данный момент, могут иметь 37 разных представлений о том, что значит фраза "она стопорится". Формулируйте четче. Выж программист? Это связано с тем, что у Вас нет формы с атрибутом `name="formname"`, и скрипт не может прочитать свойство "`item_name_1 of undefined`".

Comment: Прошу прощения, что не указал здесь имя формы. В моей коде name="formname" . Теперь пробую ваш варинат. Откоментировал по нему ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.formname` в Вашем коде обращается к одной единственной форме в документе - форме с атрибутом `name="formname"`, если такая форма вообще существует. Определим обработчик события `onsubmit` для каждой формы, куда будем подавать ссылку на саму форму.

```js
    function codename(aForm) {
      var count = 0;

      aForm.item_name_1.value='';
      //...
      aForm.amount_1.value='';
      //...

      if(aForm.item1.checked)
      {
        aForm.item_name_1.value = "One more variant of interior";
        aForm.amount_1.value = "5.00";
        count=count+1;
      }
      //...
    }
```

```html
    <form onsubmit="return codename(this)">
    
      <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="Item 1" />
      ...
      <input type="text" name="amount_1" />
      ...
      <input type="text" name="item_name_1" />
      ...
    
      <input type="submit" border="0" name="payment" />
    </form>
    <form onsubmit="return codename(this)">
    
      <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="Item 1" />
      ...
      <input type="text" name="amount_1" />
      ...
      <input type="text" name="item_name_1" />
      ...
    
      <input type="submit" border="0" name="payment" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37103/discussion-on-answer-by-igor----).